# IntelliJ IDEA plugin - Navigate to line inside PsiClass

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to navigate to specific line in a PsiClass from IntelliJ IDEA plugin

I tried the following code

```
public static void navigateToClass(final PsiClass psiClass, int line) {
    PsiElement element = psiClass.getContainingFile().findElementAt(line);
    if (element instanceof Navigatable){
        ((Navigatable)element).navigate(true);
    } else
        psiClass.navigate(true);
}
```

But the problem is that `findElementAt` takes an offset not line number. Is there exist any other method that can find an element in with line number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new OpenFileDescriptor(psiClass.getProject(), psiClass.getContainingFile().getVirtualFile(), line, 0).navigate(true)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find this bit of information in the official documentation. Thank you for pointing out.